# Delete image Doc from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a document from firebase firestore collection
how can I do that , I tried few things but no success
here is my code

**here is the Firestore hook**

```
const useFirestore = (somecollection) => {

    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);


    useEffect (() => {
        // new collection reference
          const newcoll = collection(projectFirestore, somecollection);
          const q = query(newcoll, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
          const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
            let documents = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
               documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            })
            setDocs(documents);
          });
     
          return () => unsub;

    },[somecollection]);
    
    return { docs };
}
```

the imagegrid where all the images are shown (only the js without the jsx return)

```
const { docs } = useFirestore('images');

  const handleDelete = (e) => {
    docs.forEach(doc => {
      deleteDoc(doc);
    })
```

now , on the imagegrid jsx I have all the uploaded images that store the document in them.

so I added a button to every image and I want that when I click the button its fires a handleDelete() that delete this specific image document from the firestore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to have a button that deletes a single document, you likely do NOT want to be looping over all of the docs and calling `deleteDoc()`.

Instead, your UI would likely display each image and include its ID for each button.  Something like:

```
const deleteOneImageDoc = async (docId) => {
  try {
    let docRef = doc(myFirestore, `images/${docId}`);
    await deleteDoc(docRef);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(`Delete FAILED: ${ex.message}`);
    throw ex;
  }
};

return <div>
  docs.map((imgDoc) => {
    return (
      <div key={imgDoc.id}>
        <img src={imgDoc.url}/>
        <button onClick={() => deleteOneImageDoc(imgDoc.id)}>
          delete {imgDoc.id}
        </button>
      </div>);
    })
  </div>;
```

Comment: First , thanks for the explanation , now I understand the problem, 
but its doesn't worked, I try to console.log the id and its works but its throws me an error:

Delete FAILED: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Comment: Why are you using `collection()` ?  Or is it possible that you are not passing a `docId` ?

Comment: I fixed it , just added on doc(``) the firestore collection isnstance the firestore (db) for example const db = getFirestore(), but Thank you

Comment: Edited the response to add the `myFirestore` parameter to `doc()`

Comment: great , Thank you